# Why won't this snippet, to rename the executable to a temporary file, work as expected?

Tags: c++, file, temporary

I would assume that in the following snippet of code, the file would be renamed to the temporary file, and then disappear once execution is complete. But it doesn't work like that, and the executable still exists after being run.

Shouldn't the file be able to be renamed while running?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc_, char** argv_)
{
    char rename_path_buffer[L_tmpnam_s];
    tmpnam_s(rename_path_buffer, L_tmpnam_s);

    rename(argv_[0], rename_path_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider to check return values and `errno`?

Comment: Pretty sure temp files don't get immediately on exit -- the system just deletes them eventually (either on reboot, or in a cron job or the like).

Comment: I get -1 for when I call rename. And I think you're right about that @cHao , for some reason i can't rename files to it.

Comment: Oh and I get errno 13, which is ERROR_INVALID_DATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is locked against renaming while it is being executed.
Try to manually rename it while it is running, and you will get a corresponding error message; or check the return value of the rename function.

Comment: I'm able to rename a running executable, to temp.file when I tried it, but when I try to rename a file to the temporary path it never works. And I get -1 as the result for the `rename` function.

Comment: Renameing only works to a different _name_. You can’t _rename_ into a different folder, that’s called moving.